# Can't delete "empty" folder in terminal mac os

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, rm

Mac OS - 
I have this folder .Trashes/ in a MS-DOS (FAT32) partition.
Trying to **rm -rf** and I get this

```
MacBook:.Trashes ###$ rm -rf 501/
rm: 501//backup-www-18-01-18/www2/wp-content/uploads/2017/0e4: Directory not empty
rm: 501//backup-www-18-01-18/www2/wp-content/uploads/2017: Directory not empty
rm: 501//backup-www-18-01-18/www2/wp-content/uploads: Directory not empty
rm: 501//backup-www-18-01-18/www2/wp-content: Directory not empty
rm: 501//backup-www-18-01-18/www2: Directory not empty
rm: 501//backup-www-18-01-18: Directory not empty
rm: 501/: Directory not empty
```

If I **ls -la** 0e4 I get

```
MacBook:0e4 ###$ ls -la
total 128
drwxrwxrwx  1 john  staff  32768 17 Mag 16:07 .
drwxrwxrwx  1 john  staff  32768 17 Mag 15:26 ..
```

If I **cd and tab** from 501 I get a longer path and it looks like 0e4 forlder is full jpg..

```
MacBook:501 ###$ cd backup-www-18-01-18/www2/wp-content/uploads/2017/0e4/Hambù_
Display all 159 possibilities? (y or n)
Hambù_01_ap-design-1-500x600.jpg  Hambù_03_ap-design-1-550x550.jpg  Hambù_05_ap-design-1-550x550.jpg  Hambù_07_ap-design-1-550x550.jpg  Hambù_09_ap-design-1-550x550.jpg...
```

- Any idea of what is going on?
- How can I empty my trash?
- Why there is a double // in my path?

Comment: Try typing 'rmdir directory_name".  if directory is empty this should delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem today - did you use the FAT partition with macOS *AND* Windows? I did this with an ExFAT formatted USB stick and could not empty the Trashcan due to some "invisible" items.

I put the items from the Trashcan back to the ExFAT partition and then successfully deleted the Folder with Windows.

Voila!
   swobi

Comment: Yep macOS and Windows.. I just formatted the all thing that time: if it comes out again I'll try what you did..